# Environment.GetCommandLineArgs in a Windows 8 Store App

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-store-apps

I created a brand new, vanilla c# Windows 8 Store app. In the App() function, I put a line of code to gather the Command line arguments. The IDE complains that GetCommandLineArgs() is not part of Environment.

```
public App()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    this.Suspending += OnSuspending;

    String[] arguments = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
}
```

[This page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.getcommandlineargs.aspx) on Microsoft's site seems to indicate that this is supported in .NET 4.5. What gives?

(I could technically gather the args as an App() parameter, but I'd prefer not to. Other lines of code also call this, and I'd prefer to leave them "as is". Moreover, I'm just curious why this isn't working, seems like it should.

Comment: Curious.. what if you fully qualify it?

Comment: But it's not supported in Windows Store apps. They are different. If it was there would be a section in Version Information like ".NET for Windows Store apps"

Comment: If you look at the [Environment Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z8te35sa.aspx) you can see which Methods/Properties are supported in a Windows Store application by looking at the Icons to the left of the Name

Answer (score 1):

How would you pass in an argument to a Windows Store app on the command line?  The closest analog would probably be [LaunchActivatedEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.applicationmodel.activation.launchactivatedeventargs.aspx) which comes into play, for instance, if you have secondary tiles (say a tile for the weather in Boston and one in Honolulu - same app, different arguments).

Check out [How activate an app](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465102.aspx) for additional details.

**UPDATED in response to Todd's first comment.**

What you're looking for then is [File Activation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/Hh779669%28v=win.10%29.aspx).  You can indicate your file knows how to process, say .txt files.  When user right clicks on a .txt file in File Explorer, your app will appear as an "Open With.." option.  When the user picks your app as the one he/she wants to use to process the file, your app will launch (or just activate if already running) and its [OnFileActivated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.application.onfileactivated.aspx) event will fire, through which you can get to the file(s) that were selected.

Comment: My plan is to right-click a file in Windows Explorer and have the app launch in response and process the file.

Answer (score 0):

If you read the description of [Environment Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z8te35sa.aspx), it clearly states that the api is only applicable for following OS's

> ## Platforms
>
> **Windows 8, Windows Server 2012, Windows 7, Windows Vista SP2, Windows Server 2008 (Server Core Role not supported), Windows Server 2008 R2 (Server Core Role supported with SP1 or later; Itanium not supported)**
>
> The .NET Framework does not support all versions of every platform. For a list of the supported versions, see .NET Framework System Requirements.

Only functions marked with store symbols are supported for windows store apps though.

## Functions for Windows Store Apps

[image]

## Functions for non WinRT/Windows store applications

[image]

It doesn't really makes sense for Windows store apps to have [Environment.GetCommandLineArgs Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/system.environment.getcommandlineargs.aspx) since one can't really pass command line arguments to the Windows store applications.

There are only 5 properties and one method available for `WinRT/Windows store apps` in `Environment` class.

## Properties

1. [CurrentManagedThreadId](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.currentmanagedthreadid.aspx)
2. [HasShutdownStarted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.hasshutdownstarted.aspx)
3. [NewLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.newline.aspx)
4. [ProcessorCount](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.processorcount.aspx)
5. [TickCount](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.tickcount.aspx)

## Methods

- [FailFast(String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131100.aspx)
- [FailFast(String, Exception)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd289240.aspx)

Comment: @BoltClock I mean to say other then WinRT/Windows Store application api.